# How to set up an "always/finally" node in an Ansible workflow template?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible Automation Platform workflow template and I want to add a job to report the completion status of the template to a REST API, whether it fails or not--similar to the `Finally` section of a [Tekton pipeline](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelines/#adding-finally-to-the-pipeline). The problem is, if a node fails it obviously doesn't continue to the next one so if I put the "reporting" node at the end it won't be run.

So just as an example, say my workflow looks like this:

```
Start --> Node1 --> Node2 --> Node3 --> Node4
```

I could put it multiple times throughout the workflow:

```
Start --> Node1 -"on success"-> Node2 -"on success"-> Node3 -"on success"-> Node4 -"on success"-> ReportStatus
            \                      \                    \
          "on fail"               "on fail"            "on fail"
              \                      \                    \
               > ReportStatus         > ReportStatus       > ReportStatus
```

But this is obviously pretty messy to add the node off of every single node, especially when we've got workflows with like 15+ nodes.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?